# AWS S3 download over https times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my front end application, I'm storing media in S3 and retrieving it with a fetch request. This worked fine from my local machine, running http://localhost and making an http request to S3, but started failing when I deployed the application to the web and started serving it over https. The failure was

> The page at [URL] was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure
> resource
> 'http://ofanymdev.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files/1707231907747-download1.jpeg'.
> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I went into AWS Cloudfront and created a new distribution with the origin domain being the bucket's origin, ofanymdev.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, hoping that it would allow me to access the bucket over https in the browser, and am trying to access the file above via https, but the requests just time out now.

What do I need to configure, and how do I need to configure it in order to access these files from the front end with a fetch request?

Comment: Does that page contain an `<img>` tag that references the JPG file? If so, check the URL to see whether it is specifically asking for it via HTTPS.

Comment: No, I'm streaming directly to the file system the second the fetch comes back, not displaying it at all. The fetch is using https and timing out.

Comment: Okay, so the core problem is that you can't retrieve the image using HTTPS. It's quite unusual that the request is hanging like that. It seems to work fine when accessing S3 without the website endpoint: `https://ofanymdev.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files/1707231907747-download1.jpeg` Did you active the website endpoint on the bucket? Any objections to just going direct instead?

Comment: Thank you. how do I activate the website endpoint, and is there any disadvantage to going direct?

Comment: Oh, you didn't activate the website endpoint? That would explain why your URL isn't working, but it also shouldn't be working for HTTP. For details, see: [Website endpoints - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html). However, I don't think it is necessary for your use-case -- just point to the object directly without using a website endpoint (as shown in the above URL).

Comment: Thanks, that works. If you want to make this an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your URL:

```
http://ofanymdev.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files/1707231907747-download1.jpeg
```

It contains `s3-website-eu-west-1` that indicates it is being used as a [Website endpoint - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html). This gives it extra capabilities such as:

- Configuring an `index` and `error` page
- Configuring redirects
- [Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

I suggest you **check that you have enabled website hosting**. See: [Enabling website hosting - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EnableWebsiteHosting.html)

Alternatively, your code could use a URL that does *not* involve website hosting:

```
https://ofanymdev.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files/1707231907747-download1.jpeg
```